# Docker Swarm: Joining the node not working

Tags: docker, host, swarm

I am trying to join a worker node to a manager in another machine. The former one is Mac and later one is Windows. The worker host on Mac have a response:

> Timeout was reached before node joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.

When I typed the Join-Token command again, I received response saying the

> This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.

When I typed the command in manager side:

> docker node ls

it only show one node which is the manager node.

Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker1.12 Worker not able to join in cluster(Swarm: Pending)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693560/docker1-12-worker-not-able-to-join-in-clusterswarm-pending)

Answer (score -1):

Do you use the same docker version on all hosts?